SqlAlchemy join load parent tables
I have three tables with relationshps on them:
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    bs: Mapped[List['B']] = relationship(
        lazy='select',
        passive_deletes='all',
        back_populates='table_b',
    )
    some_attribute: Mapped[int]

    
class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_b'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    a_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('table_a.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'),
        unique=True,
    )
    cs: Mapped[List['C']] = relationship(
        passive_deletes='all',
        lazy='select',
        back_populates='table_c',
    )
    some_other_attribute: Mapped[str]

class C(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_c'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    b_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('table_b.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'),
        unique=True,
    )
    uuid: Mapped[str]

I have many other one-to-one tables under C.
I want to be able to query C also get some_attribute and some_other_attribute but they are currently resulting in multiple queries.  given that I know I'll need the data, I'd like to do some kind of query to get the columns from A and B.
I am trying to write a query like this:
A.query.join(B).join(C)
        .filter(C.uuid==c_uuid)
        .options(joinedload(C.sub_table_1))
        .options(joinedload(C.sub_table_2))
        .options(joinedload(C.sub_table_3))
        .first_or_404(f'C not found for uuid {c_uuid}.')

but I am encountering:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped class Mapper[C(table_c)] does not apply to any of the root entities in this query, e.g. Mapper[A(table_a)]. Please specify the full path from one of the root entities to the target attribute.

I can't seem to figure out how to specify that full path given that the relationship is one-to-many from parent to child.
I tried setting up the query from C but I can't figure out how to do a joined load on A and B to get the attributes.

I opened a discussion on the project: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/11577

Answered on GitHub here
